# Linq Select with Or Statement VS Separate Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have avareage 30 tables and I want to scan all datas in all tables but I get an timeout error in MVC project with Entity Framework. You imagine that scan data for each letter in alphabeth like this code;

```
               foreach (var item in db.A_Player.Where(i=>i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv || i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdDep))
                {
                    PlayerEntity player = new PlayerEntity()
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId

                    };

                    if (item.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv)
                    {
                        playerListEv.Add(player);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerListDep.Add(player);
                    }

                }
                foreach (var item in db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv || i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdDep))
                {
                    PlayerEntity player = new PlayerEntity()
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId

                    };

                    if (item.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv)
                    {
                        playerListEv.Add(player);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerListDep.Add(player);
                    }

                }
```

Question to solve issue that can I use seperate queries like below code or are both the same ? These both give the same result as speed? How can I exceed time out error?

```
foreach (var item in db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv))
                {
                    PlayerEntity player = new PlayerEntity()
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId

                    };

                    if (item.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv)
                    {
                        playerListEv.Add(player);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerListDep.Add(player);
                    }

                }

                foreach (var item in db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdDep))
                {
                    PlayerEntity player = new PlayerEntity()
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId

                    };

                    if (item.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv)
                    {
                        playerListEv.Add(player);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerListDep.Add(player);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: 1) you should optimize the db operations. Does `CurrentTeamId` has a Index? 2) There is no guarantee that timeout will not occur even if you highly optimize the query. The real problem is that you are iterating over 30 tables in a request.  Solutions can be  -  i) increased the request time out to max. ii) Check if you to fetch the data from all 30 tables for a request - Try to optimize the SQL query, and if require write SQL SP or Query directly.

Comment: Hrm this seems a little xy'ish. firstly you should use projection, and the whole scanning 30 table thing smells a bit fishy and like a table normalization problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, projection can help in the respects by minimizing the columns you are pulling back from your tables (if you have lots of columns).

Secondly, You could do 2 smaller queries instead

```
var evs = db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv)
                     .Select(x => new PlayerEntity // projection
                     {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId
                     }).ToList();

var deps= db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId != teamIdEv)
                     .Select(x => new PlayerEntity // projection
                     {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Surname = item.Surname,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        CurrentTeamId = item.CurrentTeamId
                     }).ToList();
```

Or you could project all your players and filter them in memory,

However, you need to work you what the bottle-neck here is.

- Is `CurrentTeamId` appropriately [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)?
- Is your database [Normalized](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) properly (as you said you have 30 tables)

Comment: this has provided a visible benefit

Answer (score 1):

Is your `db.B_Player` a `DbSet` of `PlayerEntities`?

If so, the foreach is not needed. You can just do:

*This is just pseudocode I don't have an IDE at my disposal right now.*

```
playerListEv.AddRange(db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdEv).ToList());
playerListDep.AddRange(db.B_Player.Where(i => i.CurrentTeamId == teamIdDep).ToList());
```